Crop image white space automatically using Angular
I'm writting an application in Angular and I have a list of images. The problem is that, each image has something like white padding, just white pixels, and I want to remove them and leave only an object on image.
I want to went from:

to:

How to achieve that? Is there any ready solution or library to handle that?

has the image the whitespace on itself? are you asking how to remove the padding from the HTML?

is white space-pixels on image like a padding, like on attached image

Is there a reason why they can't be cropped before?

there is a lot of images, I need them to be cropped automatically

I'd recommend scripting it before the images land to your Angular app with libraries like Pillow: https://irskep-pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
As alternative you can write it using native JS canvas
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

I’m not sure I’d tackle the runtime solution personally. Automatically knowing how to crop is non-trivial and likely to be hard to do in the browser in a performant and robust way. The images can and should be cropped on the server.

Yep, cropping on the go doesn't make much sense imo
